# Failed to install pymssql with pipenv

Tags: python, pymssql, pipenv

**MacOS 10.14.1:**

I cannot install pymssql within pipenv.

FreeTDS is installed with:

> brew install freetds

Then I got the error with:

> pip env install

[error log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIkVI.jpg)

How should I install pymssql in pip env?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing `brew link freetds` before installing pymssql via pipenv.

Alternatively, you might want to install an older, specific version of FreeTDS, as 
[this thread](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/129#issuecomment-367589509) on GitHub suggests.

A third way would be to install the pymssql package directly from the GitHub repository (look at [this message](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/432#issuecomment-238257092) on GitHub).